# Function that changes a variable passed by a calling function

Tags: c#

I am working on a simple [Blackjack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackjack) card game. I am using this code to calculate the user score:

```
switch (label9.Text)
{
    case "J": playerTotal = playerTotal + 10; break;
    case "Q": playerTotal = playerTotal + 10; break;
    case "K": playerTotal = playerTotal + 10; break;
    case "A": playerTotal = playerTotal + 11; break;
    default: playerTotal = playerTotal + Convert.ToInt32(label9.Text); break;
}
```

But I don't want to write this over and over again. So I placed this code inside a function:

```
public void score(Label n, int m)
{
    switch (n.Text)
    {
        case "J": m += 10; break;
        case "Q": m += 10; break;
        case "K": m += 10; break;
        case "A": m += 11; break;
        default: m += Convert.ToInt32(n.Text); break;
    }
}
```

**Now, here's the problem:** When I call `score(label7, playerTotal)` from another function, the value of `playerTotal` does not change. For example:

```
public void hitPlayer()
{
    //ilk hit
    if (hitCounter == 0)
    {
        label7.Text = newDeck.Last();
        playerHand[2] = newDeck.Last();
        newDeck = newDeck.Take(newDeck.Count() - 1).ToArray();
        label7.Visible = true;
        pictureBox7.Visible = true;

        score(label7, playerTotal); // <<===== 'playerTotal' does not change
        aceFound(hitCounter);
        label12.Text = playerTotal.ToString();
    }
```

However, when I use the `switch/case` code *without* wrapping it inside a function, the value of `playerTotal` *does* change. What's wrong with the way I am calling the `score()` function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A third alternative, which I prefer to either re-assigning the score or passing it by reference:

```
public int getScore(Label n)
{
    switch (n.Text)
    {
        case "J":
        case "Q":
        case "K":
            return 10;
        case "A":
            return 11;
        default:
            return Convert.ToInt32(n.Text);
    }
}
```

...

```
playerTotal += getScore(label7);
```

Answer (score 4):

Pass `m` as *ref*

```
public void score(Label n, ref int m)
{
    switch (n.Text)
    {
        case "J": m += 10; break;
        case "Q": m += 10; break;
        case "K": m += 10; break;
        case "A": m += 11; break;
        default: m += Convert.ToInt32(n.Text); break;
    }
}
```

As suggested by @Andrew

```
public void score(Label n, ref int m)
{
    switch (n.Text)
    {
        case "J": 
        case "Q":
        case "K": m += 10; break;
        case "A": m += 11; break;
        default: m += Convert.ToInt32(n.Text); break;
    }
}
```

---

```
score(label7, ref playerTotal);
```

Comment: Or return m at the end of the function! :P

Comment: @Jite of course, I also don't like using `out`s and `ref`s.

Comment: Why not join the JQK cases?

Comment: @Andrew I just gave an answer close to the he OP's question. of course there may be better ways of doing it.

Comment: I know, it was just a suggestion in order to easily enhance it a bit more. :)

Answer (score 2):

Your score method needs to return m. m is an integer and is not treated as a reference. Any changes to m inside your method won't alter the integer you passed in.

playerTotal = score (label7, playerTotal);

You can alter your method so that playerTotal is treated as a reference by adding "ref", as pointed out by the other answer, but it's not a good design since your method only has a single success state.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, Label is an object, so it's passed by reference, however, int that you are passing is a primitive type, thus it's passed by value(copied inside your method), so you need to return the int from your method.

```
    public void hitPlayer()
    {
        //ilk hit
        if (hitCounter == 0)
        {
            label7.Text = newDeck.Last();
            playerHand[2] = newDeck.Last();
            newDeck = newDeck.Take(newDeck.Count() - 1).ToArray();
            label7.Visible = true;
            pictureBox7.Visible = true;

            **playerTotal** = score(label7, playerTotal);
            aceFound(hitCounter);
            label12.Text = playerTotal.ToString();


        }

    public int score(Label n, int m)
    {
        switch (n.Text)
        {
            case "J": m += 10; break;
            case "Q": m += 10; break;
            case "K": m += 10; break;
            case "A": m += 11; break;
            default: m += Convert.ToInt32(n.Text); break;

        }
        return m;
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The `int m` parameter in the `score` method is a copy of the original value. You are only changing this copy.

You'd better separate the logic from any lables and textboxes. Also don't create side effects within the `score` or `CardValue` method, i.e. don't change things besides returning a result value.

```
public int CardValue(string card)
{
    switch (card)
    {
        case "J": return 10;
        case "Q": return 10;
        case "K": return 10;
        case "A": return 11;
        default: return Convert.ToInt32(card);
    }
}
```

The use it like this (it looks cleaner):

```
playerTotal += CardValue(label7.Text);
```